# How to use only one program that can train and evaluate the model in object detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

Is there a solution that uses only one program that can train and evaluate the model in object detection, and can stop training the program when the loss value no longer decreases?

I would like to be able to use a program where the training and model evaluation are happening simultaneously and can be stopped as the EarlyStopping I did in imageclassify. What are some ideas for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is "EarlyStopping"?

Comment: Related: *[Standard for machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/standard-for-machine-learning-questions)* and *[Guidance for asking machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378431/guidance-for-asking-machine-learning-questions)*

Comment: And *[Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/do-pure-machine-learning-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow)*.

Answer (score 0):

Training and evaluation can take places simultaneously, but it will lead to [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

According to the concepts of classical machine learning, we split the data into train and test data sets.

Then we train the model on the training data set and use the unseen test data to make predictions.

While building the model, we do often evaluate the model performance over the train and test data separately.

If the model performs well on the train data, but not that well on test data, it is called overfitting.

Hence these two methods should be treated **distinctly and not parallelly** , meaning which *training* will happen after evaluation.

Moving to the second part of your question, **early stopping**:

[Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) has a feature called [callbacks](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) wherein you can stop the training once you reach the desired accuracy.
You can configure and use a callback this way:

```
my_callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs'),
]
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

The entire code for *object detection* using Keras + callbacks can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/guides/ipynb/keras_cv/object_detection_keras_cv.ipynb#scrollTo=30rwmHx0Utsy).

Comment: I thank you very much for the information you provided. I will start learning object detect using keras instead of tensorflow api!

Comment: Keras is a wrapper over Tensorflow. It is nothing but low code Tensorflow. For learning Keras you will surely need to learn on the basis of Tensorflow. PyTorch is also a great platform for beginners as it is MUCH SIMPLER than Tensorflow.